# Mongo/DataNucleus/JPA with embedded type query gives: Cannot find type of (part of) ... since symbol has no type; implicit variable?

Tags: mongodb, jpa, datanucleus

I am trying this JPA query `"SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml WHERE ml.media.id = :id"` and I get this error message: `"Cannot find type of (part of) ml.media.id since symbol has no type; implicit variable?"`

I realize that should probably be some kind of `MEMBER OF` query instead but I tried that with the same result. I am looking to find the media library containing the media with the id equal to the given value.

Simplified code:

```
@Entity( name = "MediaLibrary" )
@Table( name = "MediaLibrary" )
public class MediaLibrary implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String mediaLibraryKey;

    @Embedded
    private Set<Media> media;
....

@Embeddable
public class Media implements GenericDataProducer, CreationDateKnown, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    private String id;
....
```

My Mongo data looks as I expected:

```
db.MediaLibrary.find().pretty();
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51bcb440b3060638e5890581"),
    ....
"media" : [
    {
                    ....
        "id" : "f0f9b014-24b1-4408-b0aa-3c9f74c822f8",
                    ....
    }
]
}
```

**UPDATE**: the working commandline mongodb query is this:

```
db.MediaLibrary.find( { "media" : { $elemMatch : { "id" : "f0f9b014-24b1-4408-b0aa-3c9f74c822f8" } } } );
```

or in java:

```
new BasicDBObject( "media", new BasicDBObject( "$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("id", id) ) );
```

**UPDATE**: another query: `"SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml WHERE :id MEMBER OF ml.media.id"`

and output at level FINE:

```
FINE: JPQL Single-String with "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml WHERE :id MEMBER OF ml.media.id"
Jun 16, 2013 12:47:04 PM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml WHERE :id MEMBER OF ml.media.id"
Jun 16, 2013 12:47:04 PM com.xonami.rest.server.MyServerResource log
SEVERE: com.xonami.rest.server.media.MediaStateNoIdResource in log:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Cannot find type of (part of) ml.media.id since symbol has no type; implicit variable?: Cannot find type of (part of) ml.media.id since symbol has no type; implicit variable?
     at org.datanucleus.query.expression.PrimaryExpression.bind (PrimaryExpression.java: 274)
     at org.datanucleus.query.expression.InvokeExpression.bind (InvokeExpression.java: 97)
     at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JavaQueryCompiler.compileFilter (JavaQueryCompiler.java: 475)
     at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JPQLCompiler.compile (JPQLCompiler.java: 81)
     at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery.compileInternal (AbstractJPQLQuery.java: 271)
     at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal (JPQLQuery.java: 163)
     at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.setImplicitParameter (Query.java: 811)
     at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.setParameter (JPAQuery.java: 438)
     at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.setParameter (JPAQuery.java: 58)
     at com.xonami.rest.cache.DataFetcher.getMediaById (DataFetcher.java: 205)
```

**UPDATE**

for Query: `SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id`

```
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.query.JPQLSingleStringParser 
FINE: JPQL Single-String with "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: JPQL Query : Compile Time = 2 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=ml),ClassExpression(alias=m)]
  [filter:DyadicExpression{InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{ml.media}].contains(PrimaryExpression{m})}  AND  DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{m.id}  =  ParameterExpression{id}}}]
  [symbols: id type=java.lang.String, m type=com.xonami.rest.db.Media, ml type=com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery compileQueryFull
FINE: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id" for datastore
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper compileFilter
FINE: Compilation of filter to be evaluated completely in-datastore was impossible : Invoke expression is not supported by this mapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery compileQueryFull
FINE: JPQL Query : Compile Time for datastore = 0 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.util.Imports resolveClassDeclaration
FINE: Class MediaLibrary was resolved to be com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary. It wasnt defined fully-qualified so had to be looked up; you can avoid the lookup (and improve performance) by fully-qualifying the class in the query.
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.util.Imports resolveClassDeclaration
FINE: Class Media was resolved to be com.xonami.rest.db.Media. It wasnt defined fully-qualified so had to be looked up; you can avoid the lookup (and improve performance) by fully-qualifying the class in the query.
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: JPQL Query : Compile Time = 1 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal
FINE: QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=ml),ClassExpression(alias=m)]
  [filter:DyadicExpression{InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{ml.media}].contains(PrimaryExpression{m})}  AND  DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{m.id}  =  ParameterExpression{id}}}]
  [symbols: id type=java.lang.String, m type=com.xonami.rest.db.Media, ml type=com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery compileQueryFull
FINE: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id" for datastore
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper compileFilter
FINE: Compilation of filter to be evaluated completely in-datastore was impossible : Invoke expression is not supported by this mapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery compileQueryFull
FINE: JPQL Query : Compile Time for datastore = 0 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection added to the pool : org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=null, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] for key=org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@519549e in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@4fb7a553]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl obtainNewConnection
FINE: Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is starting
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery performExecute
FINE: JPQL Query : Executing "SELECT FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id" ...
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBUtils getObjectsOfCandidateType
FINE: Performing find() using query on collection MediaLibrary for fields={ "mediaLibraryKey" : 1 , "owner" : 1 , "projectKey" : 1 , "quota" : 1} with filter={ }
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.LazyLoadQueryResult closingConnection
INFO: Reading in results for query "SELECT FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id" since the connection used is closing
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl getObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") taken from Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NYYYY]") [cache size = 5]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JavaQueryEvaluator execute
FINE: JPQL Query : Processing the "filter" clause using in-memory evaluation (clause = "DyadicExpression{InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{ml.media}].contains(PrimaryExpression{m})}  AND  DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{m.id}  =  ParameterExpression{id}}}")
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JavaQueryEvaluator handleFilter
FINE: Evaluating filter for 1 candidates
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection found in the pool : org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] for key=org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@519549e in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@4fb7a553]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler fetchObject
FINE: Fetching object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id=51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6) fields [media]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler fetchObject
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") being retrieved from MongoDB
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBUtils getObjectForObjectProvider
FINE: Retrieving object for { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6"}}
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl putObjectIntoLevel1Cache
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@44cae5b8") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNNNNNNNNN]")
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "applications" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "applications" with 1 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "cTime" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "mediaStates" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "mediaStates" with 0 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "projectVLists" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "projectVLists" with 0 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "propertyKeys" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "propertyKeys" with 2 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "propertyValues" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "propertyValues" with 2 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "searchList" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "searchList" with 6 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the value in field "tags" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.ArrayList initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" field "tags" with 2 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") is having the value in field "media" replaced by a SCO wrapper
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.types.simple.HashSet initialise
FINE: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" field "media" with 1 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler fetchObject
FINE: Execution Time = 4 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl release
FINE: Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl release
FINE: Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager updateLevel2CacheForFields
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") is having the following fields in Level 2 cache object updated : [0]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory.InMemoryExpressionEvaluator getValueForPrimaryExpression
SEVERE: Cannot find m member of com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory.InMemoryExpressionEvaluator getValueForPrimaryExpression
SEVERE: Cannot find m member of com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery performExecute
FINE: JPQL Query : Execution Time = 9 ms
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl release
FINE: Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl release
FINE: Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM com.xonami.rest.LogWrapper log
INFO: Not found.
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl performDetachOnClose
FINE: DetachOnClose : Closing manager so detaching all current objects ...
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary@9ec265c" (depth=0)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary@9ec265c" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "ownedProjects" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (depth=1)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "creationDate" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress@131b92e6" (depth=2)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress@131b92e6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress:51bf3117b306d15598ec06c8") is having the SCO wrapper in field "created" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress@131b92e6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress:51bf3117b306d15598ec06c8") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress@131b92e6 from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress@131b92e6, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="com.xonami.rest.db.EmailAddress:51bf3117b306d15598ec06c8" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 6]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "emails" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (depth=2)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (depth=2)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "applications" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "cTime" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "mediaStates" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "projectVLists" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "propertyKeys" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "propertyValues" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "searchList" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="") is having the SCO wrapper in field "tags" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@44cae5b8") has a lifecycle change : "P_CLEAN"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl evictFromTransaction
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@44cae5b8") being evicted from transactional cache
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl evictFromTransaction
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@44cae5b8") is not transactional
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650 from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.Media@64afb650, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@44cae5b8" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 5]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") is having the SCO wrapper in field "media" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6 from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary@774943d6, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="com.xonami.rest.db.MediaLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c6" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 4]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "mediaLibraries" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach
FINE: Detaching object from persistence : "com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo@6b04d3c8" (depth=2)
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo@6b04d3c8" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c7") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo@6b04d3c8 from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo@6b04d3c8, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="com.xonami.rest.db.payment.PaymentInfo:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c7" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 3]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "paymentInfos" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "projectLibraries" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "propertyKeys" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "propertyValues" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "searchList" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") is having the SCO wrapper in field "tags" replaced by the unwrapped value
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178 from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser@397b6178, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="com.xonami.rest.db.XonamiUser:8f677878-ebde-4774-9604-5f78ba4844a5" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 2]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary@9ec265c" (id="com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c5") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect
FINE: Disconnecting com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary@9ec265c from StateManager[pc=com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary@9ec265c, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache
FINE: Object with id="com.xonami.rest.db.ProjectLibrary:51bf3116b306d15598ec06c5" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl performDetachOnClose
FINE: DetachOnClose : completed detach
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl closeAllConnections
FINE: Connection found in the pool : org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] for key=org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@519549e in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@4fb7a553] but owner object closing so closing connection
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose
FINE: Connection removed from the pool : org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@517c804b [conn=com.mongodb.DBApiLayer@61ffbcb, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=false] for key=org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@519549e in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl@4fb7a553]
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl disconnectObjectProvidersFromCache
FINE: Level 1 Cache cleared
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl close
FINE: ExecutionContext "org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@519549e" closed
Jun 17, 2013 11:54:00 AM org.restlet.service.ConverterService toRepresentation
```

Comment: your quoted query is invalid JPQL, so update the question with a valid query, and the full error message and stack trace you get from that valid JPQL query. And then quote what the log says for the JPQL call (at DEBUG level!)

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong with the log output, but nothing else came up at DEBUG, so I updated with output from level ALL and a different query.

Comment: Still invalid query. ":media MEMBER OF m1.media" is a valid construct.

Comment: I don't understand your query. I have no m1. Can you suggest a JPA query that is equivalent to the the mongo db query I'm trying to perform?

Comment: I simply copy your names, and provide something valid ... which you could easily do yourself by looking at the JPA spec. If you want to specify an id then "SELECT ml FROM MediaLibrary ml, Media m WHERE m MEMBER OF ml.media AND m.id = :id"

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. It makes sense, but, unfortunately, that query returns no results, even when the equivalent mongo query does return a result.

Comment: so unfortunately you haven't looked at the LOG to look at what query was invoked then? (as per what my first comment said). And yes, it is logged

Comment: question update with the logs. I don't see it. Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FINE: Compilation of filter to be evaluated completely in-datastore
>   was impossible : Invoke expression is not supported by this mapper

so it is not currently implemented to convert JPQL "collField.contains(val)" (the equivalent of what you typed in for your query) into a MongoDB query, hence cant evaluate it in the datastore. Since you know what it needs converting into, you can easily enough get [the code for the DataNucleus MongoDB plugin](https://sourceforge.net/p/datanucleus/code/HEAD/tree/platform/store.mongodb/trunk/) and find [class QueryToMongoDBMapper](https://sourceforge.net/p/datanucleus/code/HEAD/tree/platform/store.mongodb/trunk/src/java/org/datanucleus/store/mongodb/query/QueryToMongoDBMapper.java) and contribute support for that particular query.