# Query an embedded collection inside an entity using Datanucleus and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, datanucleus

I was trying to query a embedded collection inside an entity using a query similar to the following:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u , in (u.addresses) a
WHERE a.state='xx'");
```

The query didn't return any result nor did it throw any error. I am using `Datanucleus` and `MongoDb`. Does `Datanucleus` have any limitation on such queries?

And the entity looked like:

```
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
protected long id;

@ElementCollection
protected List<Address> addresses;

public User(){
}

...

@Embeddable
public class Address {

  private String street;    
  private String city;
  private String state;
  private Integer zip;

  public Address(){
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I found a similar question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126864/mongo-datanucleus-jpa-with-embedded-type-query-gives-cannot-find-type-of-part?rq=1)

Comment: I wanted to know if IN was supported by DataNucleus.